# How do I address answers that are short and low quality, but could potentially be the right answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

I recently gained access to the LQ posts review queue and I came across this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32231193/3772221

It's  just a single sentence. `add wp_head before tag. if missing.`

It's a short, and seems like the person didn't do enough research to be sure of their answer.

It didn't look okay, I couldn't really edit it, and I feel like none of the options on recommend deletion matched the case.

Also I don't know if recommending deletion is the right step because for all I know, the guy's short, low quality answer could actually be the solution.

What's the canonical way to deal with this?

Comment: "if missing" means he's not sure if it's there or not. Should've been a comment. In general, short != bad. If it's explained, correct, and precise, short can be the best kind of answers

Comment: there also html in there that -- because it's not escaped -- doesn't show in the answer. I don't know if that makes it an answer to the question, and editing it would remove it from the queue as I understand it. I would usually skip that.

Comment: I personally think it's enough of an answer to Look Ok.  It's probably better suited as a comment, but it does seem to legitimately answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the canonical way to deal with this?

Press the "Skip" button and move onto the next review.

You don't have to do anything if you don't feel any of the actions are appropriate. Someone else will see the post who may well be qualified to take one of other actions and the post will get reviewed eventually.

Answer (score -22):

In my opinion,

Stackoverflow is a discussion board. I found questions are mainly two types, Discussion and Straight answer,

**Discussion**,
Example: people talk about their experiences, what worked for them in particular situation, some time similar problem in different situation has different solution. You see long posts here.

**Straight**,
For example, how you to do bubble sort? You don't see long post, (probably someone point to the name of a book.)

If short answer seems right to you, you can up-vote, post your comment or answer -- explaining in detail that you want others to know. Because the person who posted short answer might be really busy person (expert) the good thing is he point to right direction.

Comment: Except Stack is NOT meant for discussions, so yeah..... you're kinda wrong here. Half of the rules and quality standards of the site are there to make sure we DON'T become a discussion board....

Comment: Yes I think I made mistake there, It is question-answer right?

Comment: @Mike Right - it says that as the first sentence in the [Stack Overflow Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Also, answers to programming questions that just include the name of a book are by definition not answers.